# Laravel login TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know this question has been asked many times and I've tried everyone of them to fix my issue:

I use Laravel auth/login to login to my admin section. It's all worked perfectly well until recently when I added some new routes/views to this section. Now when I try to login, I get the TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46 error.

I have tried `php artisan key:generate` and I also have the line `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` in my form.

This is my routing for the login:

```
Route::get('auth/register', function() {  return redirect('/'); });
//stops anyone registering

Route::get('admin','AdminPagesController@adminHome');
Route::controllers([
    'auth'      =>  'Auth\AuthController',
    'password'  =>  'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

I've scratched my head and I simply don't understand what the issue is and I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm using Laravel 5

Comment: Yep, your code should work perfectly. Please take a break and recheck the form your are submitting the route your are manipulating.

Comment: I've edited my main part to show my routes. Nothing has changed. I'm totally lost! It works just fine on my local machine, it's only when I push it live.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does your production environment use a load balancer of some sort?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I don't know what you mean (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the form instead of the hidden field:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

> Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `csrf_field` helper to generate the token field

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Would this info go just in my login view or on my main app view so it is shared across the site?

Comment: @danjswade you should add this field to every form.

Comment: What about the jQuery element?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

to

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Sorry, thats my terrible typing. I do only use {{ }}. I'll edit the main section

Comment: Try to change the entire input to the `{{ crsf_field }}`

Comment: Doesn't like that FatalErrorException in d9d8ae99d37fc5cd2e75d007ae137c40 line 21:
Call to undefined function csrf_field()

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax requests you have to set that :
    1- `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in `<head></head>` section
 
    2- 
    `$.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });`

 see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Where would the ajax section go? on just the login form view?

Comment: you are requesting http request using post form or ajax ?

Comment: I use post form

Comment: you have to use `php artisan route:list` to know exactly your routes list to get the error